# iOS ECSlidingViewController delegate EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, uistoryboardsegue, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a ECSSlidingViewController with a menu in the underLeftViewController that has a few different buttons that lead to different segues to display different UIViewControllers in the ECSSlidingViewController.topViewController.  All the buttons on the menu work well and segue to the appropriate view controller.

However, I would like to be able to perform one of the segues from another UIViewController other than the ECSSlidingViewController.underLeftViewController and whenever I try to do this I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(1) error.  In my logs the following information shows up.

Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller : 0xc061250> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

2014-02-08 23:36:51.772 andrew[19995:70b] *** -[ECDynamicTransition retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11a32710

```
- (CGRect)frameFromDelegateForViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                         topViewPosition:(ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition)topViewPosition {
CGRect frame = CGRectInfinite;

NSObject *testSelf = self;
NSObject *testSelfDelegate = self.delegate;  //This is where EXC_BAD_ACCESS(1) occurs

if ([(NSObject *)self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(slidingViewController:layoutControllerForTopViewPosition:)]) {
    id<ECSlidingViewControllerLayout> layoutController = [self.delegate slidingViewController:self
                                                           layoutControllerForTopViewPosition:topViewPosition];

    if (layoutController) {
        frame = [layoutController slidingViewController:self
                                 frameForViewController:viewController
                                        topViewPosition:topViewPosition];
    }
}

return frame;
```

}

Comment: That's all it is, EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xe0b3b243)

Comment: What is the value of `self`'s delegate property?

Comment: It's a ECDynamicTransition.

Comment: Please set an exception breakpoint and provide a stack trace.

Comment: Well rather this method is called a few times after starting the segue, and the first time it completes successfully and the delegate property is a ECDynamicTransition, but the second time when it fails I don't know what it is since I can't access it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to print out the stack trace, but after turning on Zombies and setting an exception breakpoint I got a little bit more information. I'll update the question.

Comment: maybe you should set the delegate property to nil in your ViewController -(void ) dealloc method. Secondly you should check if you are not performin the segue transition two times at the same moment